# cookie expiration time with activerecord session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, session-cookies

This question is a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3/9024533). I can't seem to change the expiration time on the cookie when I switched to ActiveRecord session store. It contains just the `session_id` like it should, but its expiration time is set to HTTP session. I tried setting it in `application.rb`:

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :expire_after =>  2.hours,
}
```

But it doesn't do anything.

I could hack it by creating an additional cookie and storing a `session_id` there, but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nevermind, expiry of the *cookie* can be set by configuring ActiveRecord Session Store:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, 
    :key => 'your_cookie', 
    :expire_after => 2.hours
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question instead of just letting it sit there once you figured it out! I run into way too much of that on here. So heartbreaking.

Comment: Works for me in Rails 4 with activerecord-session_store (0.1.1)