# Where is "class Session < ActiveRecord::Base" in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

There are sessions table in rails 3 database and also a session controller. However there is no session model. Do we need to manually create Session class (session.rb. NOT by `rails generate model Session`) if we want to implement our own session time control? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3) is a post about setup session time in session class. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your database tables really doesn't need to have models. You can have tables in your database that are doing may be some auxilliary task and you can skip the models.

Comment: For session itself, I understand that there is no need for the model. However if we want to implement the session time control, we need to define some method in session model which does not exist now. That's why I am asking how to create this model. Obviously we can not use rails generate to create it since the table has been already created.

Comment: You can actually use 'rails g model session' to create the session model in that case... It won't affect what you have in the database. Or, you can also create the file manually..

Answer (score 0):

You could create the file manually in your project `app/models/session.rb` and write

```rb
# app/models/session.rb
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
end

OR

# With a different model name
class SessionManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :sessions
end
```

After that you can try any queries, for example `Session.count` - It will query sessions table

Note:
Rails generators `rails g model` are just an easy way to generate files and it is not different from, creating each file manually using file explorer