# Rails: get session timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-timeout

I can't figure out how to get the session timeout in Rails (either default or configured); [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3) it is written how to set it, but how to get it doesn't.

I tried:

- `Some::Application.config.session_store`: returns a class
- `app.controller.session.timeout`, `...expires_at`: doesn't work
- docs: no clues

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I'll leave this here for future weary travelers:

To get options defined from

```
Rails.application.config.session_store ....
```

You can do

```
Rails.application.config.session_options
```