# Sessions in rails - dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I have asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890795/rails-session-management/14890849#comment20885374_14890849)

Now I am having last problem.
I use:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = :cookie_store
```

with

```
ActionController::Base.session = { 
     #:domain      => :all,
     :key         => 'xxxxxxxx',
     :secret      => 'xxxxxxxxxxx...',
     :expire_after => 5.minutes
      }
```

This works fine and it really sets a cookie for 5 minutes of inactivity.
What I am trying now to do is when the user before logging in clicks remember me, I want to give it a longer timeout value:

This is the login action that I use:

```
session_user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])   
    if session_user

      session[:user] = session_user.id
      @user=User.find(session[:user])
      @user.update_attributes(:last_login_time => Time.now(),:is_logged => true)
      @user.save
      flash[:message]  = "Login successful."
      redirect_to "/admin"
      #cookies[:userd] = {:value => session_user, :expires => Time.now + 12}
      if params[:remember_me]

        #base.request.session_options = request.session_options.dup
        #base.request.session_options[:expire_after]= 10000.minutes
        #base.request.session_options.freeze
        #session[:expire_after] = 96000.seconds.from_now
        #ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.years
        #session[:expires] = Time.now + 1
      session[:expires_at] = 5.days
      end
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Your email or password is incorrect. Please re-enter."
    end
  end
```

As you can see in the IF (executes when the user clicked remember me), I have tried many different approaches, but none of them work, except ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.years, but that as it seems overrides permanently the [expire_after] variable.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't overriding the ActionController::Base setting what you want?  If you set it to one year, is that what you're saying is "permanent"?  Delete all but the 5th commented line in your `If` block, and test something being stored in session for the next login.  If it persists longer than 5 minutes, you've answered your own question.

For troubleshooting, delete the cookies from the browser, or by putting `reset_session` in your login action (which will leave the cookie in place, but with empty data), then remove that line for the next login.

```
ActionController::Base.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.years
```

should work.

Comment: overriding the ActionController::Base sets the value that affects everything globally. I dont need that. I simply need if you dont check remember me, then cookie will have 5 mins (as it already has) if you click remember me, then probably 3 weeks or so. I just cant make it happen, regardless what code I use (all combinations I tried are in comments)... Also code gets executed regardless of redirect_to.

Comment: @Wexoni - hey thanks for the correction on `redirect_to` - I treated it as an issue because of a knee-jerk reaction from my ASP.NET work (ASP.NET redirects are immediate, and act like a method's `return`).