# Does Rails provide default session time-out duration? If yes, where is it specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I already know how to set expiry time duration in rails app, which has been documented very well on web. But what I want to know is what is the default time duration for session expiry in rails and if there is one, where to find it?

Comment: possible duplicate --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rails doesn't have a default expiration time. [The method definition for session_store](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/318a20c140de57a7d5f820753c82258a3696c465/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L130) seems to have only one default:

On line 32 `@session_store = :cookie_store`

By default the other configurations are non existent. Therefore, `:expire_after` is not set and Rails' sessions don't have expiration time **unless** you set a value for it.

Answer (score 17):

You can configure the application's session information in the initializer file

```
config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

For setting 30 minutes try the below code :

```
 YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
    :key => '_my_session', 
    :expire_after => 30.minutes
```

Comment: I know this. But is there any default expiry period in rails?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, sessions will expire after the browser is closed, they do not have timeout.
If you open Chrome dev tools and look at the expiration date, it will say "Session" there instead of the date/time.