# User session time out in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-timeout, ruby-on-rails-4

How to do user session time out in `rails 4`. I didn't use any gem for authentication. I do my authentication manually. Any Idea please. I have already tried following and it is not working.

in my `session_store.r`b file, i added.

`key: '_Matchimi_session'`, 
`expire_after: 1.minutes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure the application's session information in the initializer file
config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  :key => '_my_session', 
  :expire_after => 30.minutes
```

[see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214800/does-rails-provide-default-session-time-out-duration-if-yes-where-is-it-specif)

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my session_store.rb (as the only line):

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_session', :expire_after => 1.minutes

I have tested it, it works.

(I presume this is configured not for a specific app, but for all)

I have rails 4.2.3.