# Rails CSRF Expiration Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a issue where some users that go idle on my site for a period of time receive a CSRF error when submitting post requests. I don't want to disable the security feature in Rails because of its importance, so I was thinking to display a page timeout alert instead. However I cannot find anywhere what the Rails default timeout is for the `authenticity_token`. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

When I look at cookies for my site Chrome shows that the session cookie expires when the `browsing session ends`. If that's the case and the reason that I get the CSRF error is due to an expired session, how does it expire if the browser is never closed?

Comment: It might be the session that expires, not the CSRF token which is tied to the session.

Comment: How could I find this out? @tadman

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is for the CSRF protection to use cookie-based sessions, and for the cookies to expire when the session expires. It sounds like the session is expiring, causing the CSRF error.

Comment: So my question then would be what is the default session expiration time?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352220/336920, there is  no default expiration. It would be set in the config.