# In rails, how to expire a session given the session id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sessionid

I just get started to learn things in ruby on rails.

In rails, how can I expire a session with a specified session session_id?

Or is it a not recommended approach in ruby on rails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of session are you using? Cookie sessions? What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe this? `Some::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
  expire_after: 24.hours
}` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended. Its self controlled according to user login and logout but there are requirements and special cases.

If you really want to do after **certain intervals**: [setting-session-timeout-in-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3).

For **specific expiration date** you can use session cookie as: [Session Cookie](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Session/Cookie).

Comment: Thanks, understood. But what if I really need to, due to  requirements for one of the other related project?

Comment: So I said, if you really need, then you can do like what I mentioned.