# Setting a manual session timeout with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want to manually trigger a session time-out after 30 seconds.  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3) SO thread to come up with the following implementation, which I put in my config/initializers/session_store.rb file

```
Nw001::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
  expire_after: 30.seconds
}
```

Works perfectly when tested in development locally (webrick).  But sessions aren't timing out on my staging server on Heroku.

How can I get session time-out working on Heroku?  Is there anything special about this sort of configuration on Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am using Devise, I was able to trigger session time-outs by this setting in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

```
  # Manually force a timeout after a set duration
  config.timeout_in = 30.seconds
```