# Ruby on Rails: Saving session variable from input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-variables, session-cookies

How do I save a session variable (maybe into a cookie) when a user inputs a location? I'd like to keep this information for future sign ins. So they won't have to retype their location multiple times.

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], :class => "search" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :loc, params[:loc], :class => "search-main", :id => "loc-search", :placeholder => "address, neighborhood, city, state or zip" %>
  <%= button_tag :type => :submit, :class => "btn btn-medium btn-inverse" do %>
    <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is in my `layouts/application.html.erb`

I'd have to set a variable if it hasn't been set yet, and display it in the field if it is already set

Comment: Why not just add a field `location` to user's model and keep it there?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev do you mean saving it into the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use cookies:

```
cookies[:name] = {
  value: 'my_cookie',
  expires: 1.year.from_now,
}
```

See more [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

You can also use [session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12016427/2503775).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
session[:location] = params[:loc]
```

Comment: everytime i close the browser, the session disappears. I've also tried `cookies[:location]`. Is it supposed to disappear?

Comment: @andrewliu yes, that is by design. Rails CookieStore uses a session cookie; session cookies are only valid until the browser is closed.